# Problemas con permisos en directorios linux winscp

Tags: java, linux

Hola chicos buenas tardes,

Estoy teniendo problemas con un servidor, revisando los logs me percaté que está apareciendo estos mensajes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error como sería el siguiente:

```
: Cannot run program "chmod": error=24, Too many open files
```

Este es el codigo java que se encarga de validar toda esa parte:

```
        public void permisosArchivos() {
                Configuracion conf = new Configuracion();
                logger.info("Inicio de Permisos");
                String so = conf.getSistemaOperativo();
        
                if (so.contentEquals("windows")) {
                    logger.info("El sistema es windows, no se otorgan permisos por so");
                    return;
                }
        
                logger.info("El sistema es Linux");
        
                List<String> lstArchivos = conf.obtenerTiposArchivos();
        
                logger.info("No. Tipos Archivos: " + lstArchivos.size());
        
                for (String Archivo : lstArchivos) {
        
                    logger.info("Permisos para: " + Archivo);
        
                    Map<String, String> directorios = conf.seccion(Archivo);
        
                    String procesar = directorios.get("procesar");
                    logger.info("Permisos para: " + procesar);
                    otorgaPermisos(procesar);
        
                    String procesadas = directorios.get("procesadas");
                    logger.info("Permisos para: " + procesadas);
                    otorgaPermisos(procesadas);
        
                    String tolalesCE = directorios.get("tolalesCE");
                    logger.info("Permisos para: " + tolalesCE);
                    otorgaPermisos(tolalesCE);
        
                }
        
                String log = "/Respaldos/TomcatCFDI/logs/";
                logger.info("Permisos para: " + log);
                otorgaPermisos(log);
        
            }
    
    private void otorgaPermisos(String sdirectorio) {
        String comando = "chmod 777 -R " + sdirectorio + "/";
    
        Comandos executa = new Comandos();
    
        try {
    
            executa.cmd(comando);
            logger.info(comando);
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(comando);
        }
    }
```

Actualizado:

Analizando como me sugirieron en los comentarios, revisé en el codigo y esta es el metodo donde por ejemplo manda los mensajes en el log:

```
public List<String> getFtpAux(String seccion) {
        
        List<String> lstArchivos = new ArrayList<>(); 
        Configuracion conf = new Configuracion();
        
        conf.getProcesId();
    
        Map<String, String> mapvalor = conf.seccion(seccion); 
        
        cargaPropiedadesGeneral(mapvalor);
        
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(userName, host, port);
            UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
            session.setUserInfo(ui);
            session.setPassword(password.getBytes());
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications",
                    "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password,gssapi-with-mic.krb5");
            session.connect();
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");

            channel.connect();

            logger.info("Connected");

            ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            channelSftp.cd(dirorigen);

            Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> filelist = channelSftp.ls(dirorigen);

            logger.info("filesList size:" + filelist.size());

            for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : filelist) {

                if (entry.getFilename().length() > 4) {
                    
                    try {
                        
                        String sArch = dirdestino +  File.separator + entry.getFilename();
                        
                        if (archivoExiste(sArch) ) {
                            logger.error("Error sftp: El archivo " + sArch + " ya existe");
                            continue;
                        } else
                            lstArchivos.add(sArch);
                        
                        File out = new File(sArch);
                        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

                        logger.info("Downloading {} --> " + sArch);
                        channelSftp.get(entry.getFilename(), bos);
                        logger.info("Archivo: " + entry.getFilename());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.error("Error sftp: " + e + "No es Archivo");
                    }

                }

            }
            
            channelSftp.exit();

            channelSftp.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            logger.info("Disconnected");
            logger.info("Termina Ftp");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error: " + e);
        } 

        
        return lstArchivos;
        
    }
```

Me habían comentado que podría ser que en la ejecución de la aplicación no se estén cerrando correctamente los archivos que se leen y que por esa razón haya llegado al limite de abrir los archivos y que el OS se haya saturado.

Sé que tiene algo que ver con los permisos a los diferentes directorios de ese servidor, me podrían por favor ayudarme si lo que menciono es correcto y también como podría solucionar ese problema? De antemano gracias y quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios, Saludos.

Comment: Esos son límites del sistema operativo al que te conectas. Revisa `ulimit`

Comment: Hola, eso en que parte se valida? gracias

Comment: En el sistema operativo donde estás haciendo el chmod.

Comment: Pero por ejemplo por que ocurre esos problemas? Conozco muy poco de servidores linux :(

Comment: Verifica que no estés dejando archivos abiertos en alguna parte de tú código y que por esto en algún momento se llegue al límite del sistema operativo.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes ya edité mi pregunta, ya estuve revisando y coloqué el codigo donde podría estar pasando eso que mencionas de que no se estén cerrando bien los archivos, ya coloqué el codigo y según yo el problema podría ser aquí BufferedOutputStream con su variable llamada "bos" que algo esté faltando?

Comment: Revisando el log si coincide donde se marca la exception  de  Error sftp: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Respaldos/TomcatCFDI/facturas/facturas/DEFR0907032220416.txt (Too many open files)No es Archivo

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Tomcat y Sistema Operativo?

Comment: Hola @Sal buenas tardes, estoy usando tomcat 9

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, como bien comentas, el *stream* que no cierras nunca (por lo menos así lo parece) pude ser la causa del error que estás teniendo.

Yo te sugeriría que uses el ***try-with-resources*** para que puedas tener garantía de que ese *stream* sí o sí será cerrado, incluso si se lanza alguna excepción.

Quedaría algo así (solo incluyo el código del `for` que está en método `getFtpAux()` por simplicidad. El resto del código quedaría cómo mismo lo tienes).

```
for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : filelist) {
    if (entry.getFilename().length() > 4) {
        // Fíjate que este código lo he sacado de dentro del `try` puesto que no es necesario tenerlo ahí
        String sArch = dirdestino +  File.separator + entry.getFilename();
        if (archivoExiste(sArch) ) {
            logger.error("Error sftp: El archivo " + sArch + " ya existe");
            continue;
        } else {
            lstArchivos.add(sArch);
        }

        // La siguiente línea es la que permite asegurar que el stream `bos` siempre será cerrado
        try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(sArch))) {
            logger.info("Downloading {} --> " + sArch);
            channelSftp.get(entry.getFilename(), bos);
            logger.info("Archivo: " + entry.getFilename());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error sftp: " + e + "No es Archivo");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, muchas gracias, lo voy a implementar el codigo que me pusiste,una duda mas, entonces los archivos que habrían quedado abiertos, los cerraría en automatico para solo en esa parte del try-with-resources? O que mas se tendría que validar?

Comment: Exacto @cratus666jose. El mecanismo del ***try-with-resources*** te garantiza que los recursos que hayas abierto dentro de este serán cerrados correctamente una vez que el flujo de ejecución del programa salga de la estructura del ***try-catch***, por lo que no tendrías que hacer nada más.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya probé el codigo y si funcionó :)

Comment: @cratus666jose me alegro de que te haya servido :)